# More than one custom value accessor matches?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I have a textarea which has custom directive q9TrimValue with a custom accessor.
So now i try to use angular material autocomplete [matAutocomplete]="auto", and get an error "More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute"

```
<textarea matInput #newMessage color="primary" mwlTextInputElement
                q9TrimValue
                [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                [formControl]="newMessageFormControl"
                [value]="newMessageFormControl.value | q9Emoji"
                ...
      ></textarea>
```

Comment: Why would you use a custom control value accessor on something that is already a control value accessor ? Please explain, and don't fall for an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I wasn't a guy who used custom accessor, it was already written for some reasons i guess.

Comment: Then see the usefulness and if it's not useful, remove it. Else, rewrite it to avoid implementing a control value accessor